# How to sign message EIP-712 with whitespace in name?

Tags: metamask, ethereum-wallet-dapp, web3.py, signature, eip712

I have a message need to sign like below

```
message = {
          "types": {
            'EIP712Domain': [{
                'name': "name",
                'type': "string"
            }, {
                'name': "version",
                'type': "string"
            }, {
                'name': "chainId",
                'type': "uint256"
            }],
            'SignIn': [{
                'name': "message",
                'type': "string"
            }, {
                'name': "Wallet address",
                'type': "address"
            }]
          },
          'primaryType': "SignIn",
          "domain": {
            "name": "DefusionAi",
            "version": "1.0.0",
            "chainId": 91715
          },
          "message": {
            "message": my_message,
            "Wallet address":address
          }
        }
```

My problem is that I can't sign message for this website because 'name': "Wallet address" and "Wallet address":address have white space , but I can't remove whitespace because if I do so, sign_message function works but it's wrong signature. The website link is [here](https://defusion.ai/)

and this is screenshot of metamask

[image]

Comment: You're right a name with whitespace doesn't make sense (https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-712.md#definition-of-typed-structured-data-%F0%9D%95%8A)  You should try to contact the project to fix it; if they don't, they may not be worth trusting or using as pretending to be EIP-712 compliant, without being so, can be nefarious.

Comment: But it's true , the link website is above , you can check it. There is a name "Wallet address" when we sign metamask

Comment: I would not recommend anyone to click the link in the question. Only suggestions are to contact the project and if you can look at the website's code on Github and see what it does. If you figure it out, please post here and we can all learn. Also, other people reading this question may find it helpful if you include the Metamask screenshot.

Comment: sure , I've just edited to add metamask screenshot above . I believe that "Wallet address" is the name in my message which has white space

Answer (score 3):

Metamask's typed-data signing implementation is more permissive than eth-account's `encode_structured_data`. A new python implementation is in process that will be more compatible with EIP712 signing as it's being used out in the wild.

In the meantime, if you don't mind a little javascript, this should generate the signature properly:

```js
const { SignTypedDataVersion } = require("@metamask/eth-sig-util/sign-typed-data")
const ethSigUtil = require("@metamask/eth-sig-util")

const test_message_json = require("./your-message.json")
const test_key = "private-key"

let v4 = SignTypedDataVersion.V4
sig = ethSigUtil.signTypedData({privateKey: test_key, data: test_message_json, version: v4})

console.log(sig)
```

Comment: Can I use this method with python code ? or it is only available with js ?

Comment: `encode_structured_data` from the eth-account library [link](https://eth-account.readthedocs.io/en/stable/eth_account.html#eth_account.messages.encode_structured_data) is the equivalent function for python. It encodes similarly for most messages, but differently (or not at all) for non-standard cases, such as spaces in a dict key.